# Show / Hide element when URL contains a specific term

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide / show specific elements of the website, if the term "/de" is contained in the URL. I tried two different codes, which don't seem to work for me.

```
window.onload = function () {
  var de = document.getElementById("german");
  var eng = document.getElementById("english");
  if (/\/search\///de(window.location)) {
    de.style.display = "block";
    eng.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    de.style.display = "none";
    eng.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var de = document.getElementById("german");
  var eng = document.getElementById("english");
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("/de") > -1) {
    de.style.display = "block";
    eng.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    de.style.display = "none";
   eng.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ((window.location.href.includes("de")) {
 //code
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for that. But is there a error in the console or just happens nothing?

Comment: id gives me a syntax error for the curly bracket after the function...

Comment: With `(window.location.href.includes("de"))` in the if?

Comment: yes  `window.onload = function () {
   var de = document.getElementById("german");
   var eng = document.getElementById("english");
    if ((window.location.href.includes("de")) {
      de.style.display = "block";
   eng.style.display = "none";
    }
 else {
  de.style.display = "none";
   eng.style.display = "block";
 }
    
        });`

Comment: I managed to do it. Had some issues with the brackets. Thanks for your help!